# How to install CSS preprocessor Sass in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: css, sass, visual-studio-2015

I went to the Tools menu and chose Extensions and Updates, then looked for Mindscape Web WorkBench and could not find it.

Does anyone know where this option is?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've fixed your English to make it clear what you mean and also make your question more discoverable. Also, I think you mean Sass rather than SAAS :)

Answer (score 0):

Per the Mindscape Web WorkBench, it is compatible with 2010 - 2013, not 2015.

http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench

Comment: I installed 'web compiler' for vs 2015 for converting .scss files to css . It is still not working.